# AFNetworking AFMultipartFormData how to set key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I want to upload (POST) image to server with setkey "FileData" like before (wrote with ASIHTTPRequest and it works)

```
[self.request setData:imageData withFileName:dateFormatted andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"Filedata"];
```

with AFNetworking I set like below:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:paramsDic constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"Filedata" fileName:dateFormatted mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];
```

seems name not actually works...
How should I set the key?  @mattt

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, the problem is I add this line

```
[afRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

But I still don't know why, I add this line to other http request and it works, but file upload. I checked server, when do file upload with this line, server received many ... hm... come to think how to describe it, mass letters ...like below:

> Content-Type: image/jpeg^M ^M
>   ÿØÿà^@^PJFIF^@^A^A^@^@^A^@^A^@^@ÿá^@XExif^@^@MM^@*^@^@^@^H^@^B^A^R^@^C^@^@^@^A^@^A^@^@<87>i^@^D^@^@^@^A^@^@^@

Answer (score -1):

hi i am uploading audio/image  file as below please check it and its working fine using the ASIHTTPRequest.

```
NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Url"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:audiourl];
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:SoundPath];
//SoundPath is your audio url path of NSDocumentDirectory.
[request addData:postData withFileName:@"mynewfile.png" andContentType:@"image/png"   forKey:@"FileData"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startasynchronous];
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks, but as I said, I used ASIHTTPRequest before, now I am doing transfer from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking, I can upload with ASIHTTPRequest but AFNetworking... because of the "forKey". Server not get that field with AFNetworking ...